# can we refer the context during initialisation?

Tags: javascript

is there a way to use 'this' while initalizing
[snippet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFXbk.png)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: Please add code as text

Comment: Also, a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers